# Google Maps iOS SDK occasional crash when destroying GMSMapView

Tags: objective-c, segmentation-fault, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

In my app I occasionally get a crash when navigating away from a view with a `GMSMapView` in it (popping it from my `UINavigationController`). It's crashing on thread 10, and here's the crash info:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000004
Crashed Thread:  10
```

And the stack trace for that thread:

```
Thread 10 name:  Dispatch queue: URLConnection
Thread 10 Crashed:
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39ef897c OSAtomicAdd32 + 0
1   CoreData                        0x31bf3de4 _PFfastQueueRelease + 24
2   CoreData                        0x31bd3ee8 -[NSManagedObject release] + 224
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31d2d30c CFRelease + 96
4   CoreFoundation                  0x31d47e96 -[__NSDictionaryM dealloc] + 130
5   Trail Tracker GPS               0x00206076 -[GMSTileDataCache .cxx_destruct] + 162
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39a90f3a object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 54
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39a8e0ce objc_destructInstance + 30
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39a8e3a2 object_dispose + 10
9   Trail Tracker GPS               0x00201810 -[GMSTileDataCache dealloc] + 172
10  Trail Tracker GPS               0x0030da12 -[GMSDASHTileService .cxx_destruct] + 318
11  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39a90f3a object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 54
12  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39a8e0ce objc_destructInstance + 30
13  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39a8e3a2 object_dispose + 10
14  Trail Tracker GPS               0x00309786 -[GMSDASHTileService dealloc] + 182
15  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39a90f3a object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 54
16  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39a8e0ce objc_destructInstance + 30
17  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39a8e3a2 object_dispose + 10
18  CoreFoundation                  0x31d2d30c CFRelease + 96
19  CoreFoundation                  0x31d37a0e -[__NSArrayI dealloc] + 74
20  Trail Tracker GPS               0x00230e84 -[GMSDASHStreamingBody .cxx_destruct] + 40
21  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39a90f3a object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 54
22  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39a8e0ce objc_destructInstance + 30
23  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39a8e3a2 object_dispose + 10
24  CoreFoundation                  0x31d2d30c CFRelease + 96
25  CFNetwork                       0x31aececa CoreReadStreamFromCFReadStream::~CoreReadStreamFromCFReadStream() + 38
26  CFNetwork                       0x31aece8a CoreReadStreamFromCFReadStream::~CoreReadStreamFromCFReadStream() + 6
27  CoreFoundation                  0x31d2d3ce CFRelease + 290
28  CFNetwork                       0x31a4f7be HTTPRequest::~HTTPRequest() + 74
29  CFNetwork                       0x31a4f76a HTTPRequest::~HTTPRequest() + 6
30  CoreFoundation                  0x31d2d3ce CFRelease + 290
31  CFNetwork                       0x31a54992 URLRequest::~URLRequest() + 106
32  CFNetwork                       0x31a5491e URLRequest::~URLRequest() + 6
33  CoreFoundation                  0x31d2d3ce CFRelease + 290
34  CFNetwork                       0x31a4464c __CFURLCacheNode::~__CFURLCacheNode() + 40
35  CFNetwork                       0x31a429de __CFURLCacheNode::~__CFURLCacheNode() + 6
36  CFNetwork                       0x31a4f57e __CFURLCache::RemoveResponseFromCacheContainers(__CFURLCacheNode*, _CFCachedURLResponse const*, __CFString const*, bool) + 158
37  CFNetwork                       0x31a4d71e __CFURLCache::AddResponseIntoCacheContainers(__CFString const*, __CFURLCacheNode*, bool) + 102
38  CFNetwork                       0x31a4d652 __CFURLCache::CreateAndStoreCacheNode(__CFURLCacheNode*, _CFCachedURLResponse const*, __CFString const*, _CFURLRequest const*, void const*, bool, bool&) + 186
39  CFNetwork                       0x31a900c8 __CFURLCache::AddCacheTask0(__CFURLCacheNode*) + 320
40  CFNetwork                       0x31a8ff78 __CFURLCache::AddCacheTask(__CFURLCacheNode*) + 28
41  CFNetwork                       0x31a4d55e CFURLCacheAddCachedResponseForRequest + 622
42  CFNetwork                       0x31ac7ac4 ___internalEvent_WillCacheResponse_block_invoke_0 + 28
43  CFNetwork                       0x31ac91ca URLConnectionClient_Classic::_delegate_willCacheResponse(_CFCachedURLResponse const*, void ()(_CFCachedURLResponse const*) block_pointer) + 42
44  CFNetwork                       0x31ac7a96 URLConnectionClient::_internalEvent_WillCacheResponse() + 586
45  CFNetwork                       0x31ac7b8c URLConnectionClient::_clientEvent_DidFinishLoading() + 172
46  CFNetwork                       0x31acdaa8 ___withClientAsync_block_invoke_0 + 20
47  CFNetwork                       0x31ac6426 ___withWorkQueueAsync_block_invoke_0 + 10
48  CFNetwork                       0x31af0e34 ___performAsync_block_invoke_0 + 24
49  libdispatch.dylib               0x39ea911c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
50  libdispatch.dylib               0x39ea8996 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$up + 142
51  libdispatch.dylib               0x39ea8890 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 32
52  libdispatch.dylib               0x39eb7212 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 190
53  libdispatch.dylib               0x39eb73b4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
54  libsystem_c.dylib               0x39edda0e _pthread_wqthread + 358
55  libsystem_c.dylib               0x39edd8a0 start_wqthread + 4`
```

Has anyone seen crashes like this from `GMSMapView` or the Google Maps SDK?

Comment: Can you show us what you do in that thread, if it's yours? I had a similar crash in code I wrote and the problem was this: I posted a block off to the global concurrent queue; that block created a new Core Data managed object context, did a bunch of things and exited. The crash occurred because some managed objects were able to outlive that context by sitting in the autorelease pool — presumably I supplied one as a return result. So the solution was to wrap everything between the context being created and explicitly destroyed in an `@autoreleasepool`.

Comment: The thread isn't mine. I assume it is Google Maps retrieving or updating tiles.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Xcode 5 - DP 5 and a previous version of the Google Maps SDK. I upgraded the SDK and things seemed to go away.